# Pulling duplicate items from print server

Tags: powershell, server, combobox

I have a script that has two comboboxes. The first selects a location, the second populates depending on the first combobox selecteditem and displays available printer names for that location.

What I see happen more often than not is the list has duplicates of all of its items. Code below;

```
$Hospital = Get-Printer -ComputerName \\PrintServer | where {$_.Name -like “*Name*”}

$ComboBox_Location.Add_SelectedIndexChanged{

switch ($ComboBox_Location.SelectedItem){

    "Hospital"{
        $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Clear();
        foreach($Name in $Hospital){
        $ComboBox_Printer.Items.Add("$($Name.name)");
        }
}
```

I can provide more code if it is needed. I believe the problem is in this particular code, but you can tell me otherwise. I also took out the ("$($Name.name)") and replaced it with "$Name.name", the following are results of the test;

MSFT_Printer(Name="PrinterName")
MSFT_3DPrinter(Name="PrinterName")

They were the same name. It was the duplicate. Is something needing a change in my print server?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong. The devicetype was not defined. It needed to be;

```
$Hospital = Get-Printer -ComputerName \\PrintServer | where {($_.Name -like “*Name*”) -and ($_.DeviceType -eq "Print")}
```

This excluded any other types of devices (like the 3DPrinter) from populating in the list.